# How can I save a document to a different location each time a new iteration is made?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, word-automation

Here is the scenario; 
I have a Visual Basic enabled document that is being saved as a PDF upon a button push when the user completes the document. 
The pdf only has one name. By default it is being saved to the same folder as the original document (totally fine), but since all the pdf's share the same name, it overwrites the last pdf of the same name.
I can still see all the past pdf's in the version history so that got me to thinking.

Me and a colleague are working to fix the code so there is some sort of unique identifier in each document that we can incorporate into the title, but it's proving challenging 
Does anyone know of a quick way to just make it so each time the pdf is replaced the old one moves to a different folder? Or any other kind of fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are in control of the VBA that creates the PDF, so you can change the file name.

Instead of one Save operation, do two:

- file name with some kind of identifier, like a date/time stamp
- file name that stays the same each time

Save both files in the same location, then you have the full history and the original file with its version history.